# function needs to stop from executing when the condition is not met but it still executes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to stop the function to be executed when the condition isn't met (`if (numCharacter > "7" || numCharacter < "129"`) but for some reason it still executes when I test with invalid input (e.g 3 or 1000). Could anyone see what went wrong?

```
     if (numCharacter > 7 || numCharacter < 129) {

     if (numbers){
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(numbArray);

    }

     if (uppercases){
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(uppercaseArray);

    }

     if (lowercases){
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(lowercaseArray);

    }

     if (characters){
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(characterArray);
    }
    console.log(resultArray)


    for (var i = 0; i < numCharacter; i++) {

      userArray.push (resultArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * resultArray.length)]); 
      }



      return userArray.join("") ;


}

}
```

Comment: you have to return to exit the function, and > 7 || < 129 includes all numbers, do you mean >7 && < 129?

Comment: What is the condition you are trying to write in plain words? That is, can you say in plain english the condition? Once you do that, also see @user120242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`||` means if either statement is true, it will return true.  You want `&&`, which will only be true if both statements are true.

```
if (numCharacter > 7 && numCharacter < 129) {
```

To exit a function you need to use `return`